# Multiple Dynamo DB calls from Lambda Node JS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I need to loop through a json and make multiple getitem calls to dynamo db. My issue is that node js flies through the code not waiting for the function return so I can't create an xml that has a header, multiple calculated lines, and then a footer.

In the sample below, the !make footer would be written long before the function taxrate finishes. How can I force the script to wait for the taxrate function to finish?

```
!make xml header 
 for(i=0; i<linelength; i++)
    {

        business_unit = '100'
        invoice_line = 1
        total = 100
        taxrate(business_unit, invoice_line, total);       
        !write line xml
    }
!make xml footer

function taxrate(business_unit, i, gross_total) {

        const params = {
            Key: {
                "tax_rate": {
                    S: business_unit
                }
            },
            TableName:"tax_table"
        };
        dynamodb.getItem(params,function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                console.log("call error");
                console.log(err);

            } else {
               console.log(data.Item.tax.N);
               return(data.Item.tax.N);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several patterns for solving this problem; the first one is one you've already got in your code, which is the callback function. The function you are passing to `dynamodb.GetItem()` is a callback that executes after some other code is run, so that the result (`data`) can be accessed.

A more modern way is to use [Promises](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies), which take a bit of time to understand. It's worth doing this though, so that you can understand what's happening behind the scenes when you use the newest way, which is `async` and `await`, which would look like this:

```
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    !make xml header 
    for(i=0; i<linelength; i++)
        {

            business_unit = '100'
            invoice_line = 1
            total = 100
            await taxrate(business_unit, invoice_line, total);       
            !write line xml
        }
    !make xml footer   
}

async function taxrate(business_unit, i, gross_total) {
    const params = {
        Key: {
            "tax_rate": {
                S: business_unit
            }
        },
        TableName:"tax_table"
    };
    try {
        let data = await dynamodb.getItem(params).promise();
        return data.Item.tax.N;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("call error");
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Notice that both `lambdaHandler()` and `taxrate()` have been turned into `async` functions. In the for loop, we've now `await`ed the result of `taxrate()`. The callback to `getItem` has been replaced with a method that returns a promise.